How to center a SceneKit node that is off screen
MacOS Apps built with SwiftUI SceneKit render node objects centered on 0,0,0 and usually start centered on a Mac display window. The problem I want to solve is that mouse finger gestures can move the node objects out of view of the display window, in any direction and any distance. I have not found any solution to re-centering a node object in the display window.
Caleb Wells link published a SwiftUI SceneKit code example which serves as a reference.
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var scene = GameScene()

// added
@State private var options: SceneView.Options = [.autoenablesDefaultLighting, .allowsCameraControl]
...

var body: some View {
    VStack {
       SceneView(scene: scene, pointOfView: scene.cameraNode, options: options)
...

// modification in response to @codetiger
// Button to center cube on display using lookAtConstraint
    VStack {
      Button("Reset") {
        // disable .allowsCameraControls
        options = [.autoenablesDefaultLighting]
        let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: scene.cube)
        scene.cameraNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraint]
      }
    }
    .onChange(of: options) {
      //enable .allowsCameraControl()
      options = [.autoenablesDefaultLighting, .allowsCameraControl]
      let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: scene.cube)
      scene.cameraNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraint]
    }
}

Using finger gestures on a Magic Mouse can move the cube node up, down, left, and right, but also out of the display Window. It seems that something like let point2d = view.unprojectPoint(scene.cube.position) might get the offscreen coordinates of the cube, but view is not defined for the scene. I want to use a SwiftUI button press to re-center the cube object on the display window, but I have not figured out the code to move the off screen cube back into view on the display window. I want to move the cube without changing its rotations and transforms that may have been applied to it. Any help with code that can recenter the cube object on the display window would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

You need to change the camera's orientation to re-focus on the cube. You can use SCNLookAtConstraint 

Thank you @codetiger. I modified the code above to turn off .allowsCameraControl and applied lookAtConstraint to the cube. The cube does return to the center of the display window. However any previous rotations or mouse zoom resizing are lost and the cube is displayed in its initial size and position. I have not found the variables that track the location and size of the cube as it moves on the display or is resized with the shift-mouse-gesture.

My mesh is 2017 by 2017. I position my camera so it is pointing down. Then move it so the camera is in the middle and above the mesh. I used most of your code with some slight modification:
VStack {
  Button {
    // camera starts out rotated, over the mesh looking down
    // cameraNode.eulerAngles.x -= CGMFloat.pi / 2                        

    // disable .allowsCameraControls and centers our map
    options = [.autoenablesDefaultLighting]

    // this is the camera node. I know it is the first node in my
    // rootNode so this makes things easy
    // this can be any position you want.
    // For a 2017x2017, this centers the mesh
    model.scene.rootNode.childNodes.first?.position = SCNVector3(x: 2017 / 2, y: 2017, z: 2017 / 2)

    // This would rotate the camera so that it is looking at a 45 degree
    // angle over the mesh. Note, you will have to change the position
    // to center the mesh in the screen.
    // model.scene.rootNode.childNodes.first?.eulerAngles.x += CGMFloat.pi / 4  

  } label: {
    Text("Reset Camera")
  }
  .onChange(of: options) {
    //---- this reenables the camera control
    options = [.autoenablesDefaultLighting, .allowsCameraControl]
  }
}

I really like your solution, it’s clean and does what I want. A little fiddling allowed me to reset the camera without adding a constraint.
Now if I can use a gesture with the .allowsCameraControl my view would be complete.

As for keeping the rotation, I’m guessing that you could store that, but you run into the complexity of rotation and position (it gets messy REAL fast). This code changes the position of the camera NOT the cube. To change the cube you need different code. The .allowsCameraControl will not help you.
